# how could I start mysql and tomcat in sequence, together with SSH in Dockerfile

Tags: mysql, tomcat, docker, ssh

I am trying start mysql and tomcat in sequence, together with SSH in one container.

I couldn't split mysql and tomcat to 2 containers since it is requested. What I did is following up mysql official Dockerfile ([link](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/Dockerfile)) and `docker-entrypoint.sh` file ([link](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh)) to create my own `Dockerfile` and `docker-entrypoint.sh` file. I tried to add some command in docker-entrypoint.sh to start tomcat or SSH, after mysql startup, but failed. I tried add this command `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.81/bin/catalina.sh run &` before `exec "$@"` in `docker-entrypoint.sh`, and I could see tomcat server is up but looks my application encountered the Java errors as below:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed

java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../logs/jeeplus/jeeplus.log (No such file or directory)

2017-10-22 12:05:18,056 WARN  [springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shiroFilter' defined in class path resource [spring-context-shiro.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'securityManager' while setting bean property 'securityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in class path resource [spring-context-shiro.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionManager' while setting bean property 'sessionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionManager' defined in class path resource [spring-context-shiro.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionDAO' while setting bean property 'sessionDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionDAO' defined in class path resource [spring-context-shiro.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'shiroCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shiroCacheManager' defined in class path resource [spring-context-shiro.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [spring-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Disk store path can't be created: ../temp/jeeplus/ehcache
```

But if I go into the container to start the tomcat manually via `catalina.sh`, my application would be up successfully.

I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you show your docker file

Answer (score 0):

**Standard practice**

You should use an init system such as s6, tini or supervisor. I recommend s6. Here is a [link](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay) to their project with ample documentation. Tini might be a better fit for you because it's extremely easy to use in comparison, here is a [link to their project on github](https://github.com/krallin/tini). There is also a walkthrough on using supervisord in the docker documentation over [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/).

**Explanation**

A choice among either of these is fine as it will ensure mysql starts up first, only then will it launch the tomcat server. This is because the error you have seems to be as a result of mysql not being ready to receive connections by the time the tomcat server is being started.

**Alternative method(quick, not recommended)**

You can fix this quickly by adding a sleep of 2-5 min before starting the tomcat server in your entrypoint script. This will ensure the mysql server has started before launching tomcat. This is not recommended.

Like so in your bash script:

```
//mysql init

... 

 sleep 5m

 ...

 //tomcat init
```

Comment: ok, thanks. actually, I tried supervisor, but I don't how how to handle sql statement execution - I mean I need run some sql statement to initialize my application data in my application. mysql official docker-entrypoint.sh provide this function to me, so I choose follow the mysql official way.

Comment: Just create a bash script that runs your sql commands and run it with supervisord too as a separate task